# Add Points to Image using Jpeg Device

Tags: r, points

I would like to add some points to an image I have created using `image.plot`. Here's my code with needed libraries. It places the .jpg in my working directory. Problem is my points are not showing up on the image. Any ideas not sure what I'm missing? Is it possible that the device is closing before points are added? Generic data is included below.

```
install.packages("RColorBrewer")
install.packages("fields")
library("RColorBrewer", lib.loc="...../R-2.15.2/library")
library("fields", lib.loc="...../R-2.15.2/library")

jpeg(paste("Steamflow", "timestep", ".jpg",sep = ''), width = 640,
     height = 441,quality = 75)
image.plot(streamflux, zlim=c(-1,1), col=brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"),  
 yaxt="n", xaxt="n", main=paste("Stress Period ", "timestep", sep = ""))
points(WLX,WLY)
dev.off()
```

And here are datasets WLX, WLY and streamflux

```
WLY=c(9, 6, 9, 13, 17, 20, 22)
WLX=c(8, 19, 29, 20, 13, 20, 21)
streamflux=matrix(1:1452,44,33, byrow=FALSE)
```

Comment: The base `image` function is not named `image.plot`. And we do not know what `brewer.pal` is.

Comment: @DWin image.plot is from the fields package.

Comment: @user2073882 Then add the appropriate library calls to your question

Comment: Ok I need to remove this question (how can I do that?) because I realized it is a problem with my data and not my code. I just had to scale my point data because I didn't specify the axis in the image.plot.

Comment: You could instead post an answer with correct `library` calls and the proper scaling. If you had been using the base-graphics image funciton you would need to do the same sort of "division-by-max"processing to get a correct  annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted before is functional however I didn't configure my data correctly. The libraries needed to run the code have been added to the original question. I used `image.plot` but I believe you would run into the same problems using the base `image`. If you only specify a matrix of z values the image is plotted with axis c(0,1). If you specify x,y,z for each cell I don't think you will run into the problem I did where points were being plotted out of bounds. If you decide that you specifying a matrix of z values is easier than specify x,y,z, as I did, to keep your points from being plotted out of bounds you will need to scale your point data. In my case `WLX=WLX/44` and `WLY=WLY/33`. As a side note you probably want to specify x,y,z if you're not using regularly spaced data.